# How to check if a variable is an array in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

My *Kotlin* code is

```
val t = cameraController.getCharacteristicInfo(myDataset[position])
if (t is Array<*>) {
     holder.keyValue.text = Arrays.toString(t)
} else {
     holder.keyValue.text = t.toString()
}
```

It is **not** working. `if (t is Array<*>)` always returns `false`.

The code of the function `getCharacteristicInfo` is:

```
public <T> T getCharacteristicInfo(CameraCharacteristics.Key<T> key) {
    return characteristics.get(key);
}
```

It is a function for getting camera characteristics.

How to properly check if a variable is an array?

Comment: Can you show us the code of `getCharacteristicInfo()`?

Comment: Ok. Added it. It it a function getting camera characteristics.

Comment: It seems `t` is not actually `Array` type. Could you edit your code to show type of `characteristics` and `myDataset[position]` as well?

Comment: show complete class

Comment: Can you show the type of `myDataset[position]` variable? `getCharacteristicInfo` returns value of type `T` related to `Key<T>` being passed as parameter. `myDataset[position]` is some kind of `Key<T>` (indeed, the code compiles) but may be is - e.g. - `Key<String>` and this forces `t` to be of type `String`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`t is Array<*>` is true for object arrays (`Array<Whatever>`), but false for primitive arrays (`IntArray` etc.). So you probably want

```
holder.keyValue.text = when(val t = cameraController.getCharacteristicInfo(myDataset[position])) {
    is Array<*> -> Arrays.toString(t)
    is IntArray -> Arrays.toString(t)
    ...
    else -> t.toString()
}
```

(if `t` is used outside elsewhere, just move the assignment outside).

Note that these are different `Arrays.toString` overloads, so you couldn't write

```
is Array<*>, is IntArray, ... -> Arrays.toString(t)
```

even if smart casts were available in this situation (they aren't).

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue and used `isArray` of the `Class`:

```
>>> arrayOf("a","b","c")::class.java.isArray
res1: kotlin.Boolean = true
>>> IntArray(1)::class.java.isArray
res2: kotlin.Boolean = true
>>> Array<String>(1) { "a" }::class.java.isArray
res3: kotlin.Boolean = true
>>> Any::class.java.isArray
res4: kotlin.Boolean = false
```

NOTE: That might not be available if your target is not JVM.